# Is there a faster way to subtract the boiling point?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner programmer. Is there a faster way to subtract a boiling point for every 300 in altitude instead of just making if statements for 300, 600, 900 and so on?

```
print("Do you use Fahrenheit (F) or Celcius? (C)")
degreeUnit = (input("Enter F or C:")).upper()
temp = int(input("What is the temperature of the water?"))
altitude = int(input("Enter altitude in meters or feet: "))
F_freezingPoint = 32
F_boilingPoint = 212
C_freezingPoint = 0
C_boilingPoint = 100

if altitude >= 300: # LIKE THIS?
altitude = altitude / 300
C_boilingPoint = C_boilingPoint - altitude
F_boilingPoint = F_boilingPoint - altitude

elif degreeUnit == "F" and temp <= F_freezingPoint:
    print("The water is frozen.")
elif degreeUnit == "F" and temp >= F_boilingPoint:
    print("The water is a gas")
elif degreeUnit == "F" and (temp > F_freezingPoint or temp < F_boilingPoint):
    print("The water is a liquid.")
elif degreeUnit == "C" and temp <= C_freezingPoint:
    print("The water is frozen.")
elif degreeUnit == "C" and temp >= C_boilingPoint:
    print("The water is a gas.")
elif degreeUnit == "C" and (temp >= C_freezingPoint or temp <= C_boilingPoint):
    print("The water is a liquid.")
else:
    print("Please try again, something went wrong")
```

Comment: Divide altitude by 300, and subtract that?

Comment: oh.... didn't think about that. I feel so stupid. thank you jarmod

Comment: The boiling point in F and the boiling point in C cannot both reduce by 1 for every 300 ft. That wouldn't make sense. You should correct for that. General rule afaik is the boiling point of water decreases by ~1/500°F for each foot increase in altitude.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

[Yes, this should be a comment, but comments don't let me format code easily.]

Your code could be a lot simpler if you just wrote:

```
if degreeUnit = "F":
     freezingPoint, boilingPoint = F_freezingPoint, F_boilingPoint
else:
     freezingPoint, boilingPoint = C_freezingPoint, C_boilingPoint
```

Then the rest of the code is just:

```
if temp <= freezingPoint:
   ....
elif temp < boilingPoint:
   ...
else:
   ...
```

Separate out the Fahrenheit/Celsius logic from the water/ice/steam logic.